# Index using temporary and filesort

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query :

```
SELECT date(DATE_SAISIE) , count(DATE_SAISIE) as total 
FROM appel_offre 
GROUP BY date(DATE_SAISIE) 
ORDER BY DATE_SAISIE
```

I have index on `DATE_SAISIE`

```
create index mi_date on appel_offre(DATE_SAISIE)
```

and this is `explain` cmd :

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appel_offre | index | mi_date       | mi_date | 6       | NULL |   25 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

in the column `extra` there is `Using temporary; Using filesort` so I think the query will be slow, How to avoid it ?

Comment: Table definition would help,but the answer is that a function on a column prevents index use.

Comment: but it use index `mi_date`

Comment: i didn't understand what is important about order by ?

Comment: @Mihai i try `order by date(DATE_SAISIE)` and i have the same explain input it use the index.

Comment: A solution is to add another column of type Date,fill it with dates from  DATE_SAISIE and query that.Btw,what type is DATE_SAISIE ?If its date,your use of DATE function is useless.

Comment: no its type is `datetime` but i want also month() and year() so i have to add other columns ... it will be not a lit bit expensive in performance not ? and in my previous comment i mean that even i use function date() on order by it use the index i got the same explain input.

Comment: Well I dont know why it says it uses the index.It cant.Maybe COUNT is involved.But you can do it in your application,just get the whole datetime and substring it in php or whatever language you are using.

Comment: yes but which one will be fast ? the the java code after i return all the result  or mysql with using temporary and filesort

Comment: Depends of the number of rows,probably more than 10 000 and you`ll HAVE to do it in the application.Just test it,there are some data generators for mysql online

Answer (score 1):

- `using temporary` means that MySQL has to create a temporary table for the purpose of generating your results.  This is because you're `grouping by` a function on a column.  If you were simply outputting the result of a function on a column, MySQL would not have to remember that value, but because you want to group all records with that function result together, it has to store those results somewhere.
- `using filesort` is an amazingly poorly-named indication that MySQL will need to sort some temporary storage in order to generate your results.  This is because you're `ordering by` a function on a column that is in the index rather than by the column itself.

One way to get rid of the filesort, or at least to make it faster, would be to order by the same thing you're selecting:

```
SELECT date(DATE_SAISIE), count(*) as total 
FROM appel_offre 
GROUP BY date(DATE_SAISIE) 
ORDER BY date(DATE_SAISIE)
```

This will give exactly the same result as your query but might allow MySQL to not have to remember the DATE_SAISIE values themselves.

Comment: So how is this answering the question?

Comment: The OP asked how to avoid `using temporary` and `using filesort`.  I have explained why they are present.

Comment: thanks man it really help me to know where the problem is from ... but my column is in `datetime` so i have to use `date()` ... @Mihai propose to me to do it in my server language (java) or add a new column in type `date`

Comment: As @Mihai states, it all depends on how much data there will be in the table.  Just because it says `using temporary` and `using filesort` does not mean that it will be slow.

Comment: it can be 100K rows ... and i try your solution to order by the same thing but i get always `using temporary` and `using filesort`